# Play UDP H.264 byte stream in UWP with MediaElement

Tags: c#, uwp, video-streaming, h.264

I'm receiving an H.264 stream over UDP from a Tello drone. I want to show the video in real time in a UWP app. I've tried writing to a MemoryStream that's assigned to a MediaSource which is assigned to a MediaElement. No joy.

```
var mediaSource = MediaSource.CreateFromStream(_stream.AsRandomAccessStream(), "video/avc");
_mediaPlayerElement.Source = mediaSource;
```

Years ago I used DirectShow. I was looking at Media Foundation, but it seems like these were deprecated many years ago.

At this point I'm at a loss for ideas to try. How can I get UDP streamed H.264 to display in a UWP app?

Comment: Sorry to be blunt, but this is a statement, not a question. Please rephrase in a way that is answerable.

Comment: [Check this documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/audio-video-camera/adaptive-streaming)

Comment: Thanks Sean. I have looked at the adaptive streaming documentation. I don't see how it can be applied to a UDP stream. I have a UDP client that listens on a port. There's no endpoint like with TCP, so I wouldn't know how to supply a URI to the MediaSource.

Comment: I take that back about the URI. I just tried "udp://192.168.10.1:11111" with no luck. I'll play with this idea a bit before giving up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UWP MediaElement has Media Foundation on its backend (Media Foundation is in good standing and it is the current low level media API in Windows including UWP). However, there is no built-in support for the protocol you are looking for. You are supposed to develop an integration layer that converts the data you have into something MediaElement can consume.

It might be a protocol handler, for example, as you basically want to inject H.264 data and format it in Media Foundation friendly way so that MediaElement could apply standard decoder and route the content through Media Foundation pipeline to presentation. Page 12 of [Media Extensions presentation](https://video.ch9.ms/sessions/build/2012/4-104.pptx) should be a good reference point in terms of API used.

Or it could also be a, presumably simpler, Media Stream Source, explained here in [Building video and audio streaming apps presentation](https://video.ch9.ms/sessions/build/2014/2-528.pptx) on slides 5, 20.

Comment: It was as simple as setting up a MediaStreamSource using VideoEncodingProperties.CreateH264() and setting the width/height manually. Then providing the UDP datagrams to the args.Request.Sample property in the MediaStreamSource.SampleRequested event. There's a bit more to it, like tracking frame rate, etc, but I have the basics working.

Comment: If anyone is curious how this worked:
https://github.com/marklauter/TelloAPI-SDK-2.0/tree/master/src/Tello.App.UWP

Comment: @MarkLauter - Do you know if there is a way to achieve what you did from a Desktop app (not UWP)?

Comment: No, I'm not sure, but the video component should be similar.